# Trying to target an element if it has a label

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Attempted to log a label to console via

```
var labelTest = document.getElementById('js_8').label;
console.log(labelTest);
```

However it is returning undefined.

Edit: correcting some stuff, sorry at work and trying to do this in between other tasks. What my end result needs to be is targeting the inner html of the js_8 ID, but with React it is different for each of the Pages that it is on. So I want to add an extra stipulatoin of having that label attribute.

HTML:

```
<span data-reactroot="" label="1715724762040702" class="_xd6" data-pitloot-persistonclick="true" display="inline" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-content="Copy Text to Clipboard" id="js_8"><div class="_xd7">1715724762040702</div></span>
```

Comment: Post your HTML structure.

Comment: Check whether your script is running _after_ the HTML element is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially I believe I am going to want to utilize var x = getAttribute("label") . The fact that the attribute was titled label confused me, and in turn I goof'd.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but this is a way to connect a `<label>` and `<input>` together via JavaScript.

```js
var some_id  = 'someid',
    my_label = getLabel(some_id);

function getLabel(id) {
  return document.querySelector('[for=' + id + ']')
}

my_label.click();
```

```html
<label for='someid'>My Label</label>
<input type='text' id='someid' />
```

Comment: Yeah, my wording was kind of messed up. Pretty much, there is a "Label" attribute on a span, and I want to only target a span with an ID that also has that label attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a `<label>` with an `<input>`, `<output>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` element in one of two ways:

The `for` attribute:

```
<label for="js_8">Test</label>
<input id="js_8">
```

Or by wrapping the element with a label:

```
<label>Test<input id="js_8"></label>
```

You can then access the associated label(s) as an array like this:

```
var labelsTest = document.getElementById('js_8').labels;

// labelsTest will be an array of 0 or more HTMLLabelElement objects
console.log(labelsTest);
```

Label-able elements can have more than one label.